# Duplicate push notification GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using the example found on the android developer website to create push notifications. They work but they problem I'm having is that the code inside `onHandleIntent()`  from `GcmIntentService` is being executed 3 times. I don't know why, it has never happened before in my other projects. I have already tried using some kind of flag with miliseconds in between but it doesn't work. Any solutions?

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

public static final String TAG = GcmIntentService.class.getSimpleName();

private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;


public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle


        /*
         * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
         * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
         * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
         * recognize.
         */
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            //sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());

        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging. MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            //sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());

        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification(extras.getString("message"));
            //Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
        }
    }
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

// Put the message into a notification and post it.
// This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
// a GCM message.
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    try {

         int icon = R.drawable.icon;
         int notificationId = 1;

         mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

         PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,MainActivity.class, 0);

         NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setContentTitle("TestApp")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setContentText(message);

         mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
         Notification notif = mBuilder.build();

         notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
         notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

         mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, notif);
    }
    catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

}

Comment: i think it was stated in their docs that push services is unreliable thus it may or may not push the or it may even push them multiple times

Comment: please post your GCMINTENTSERVICE code here.so i will give you solution.

Comment: Updated the question with the code for GcmIntentService

Comment: same problem, used same sample code from google. Any idea how to fix?